# Why am i getting no match for the cout operator while building a basic operation function?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void addnum(int x, int y) {

    cout << x + y;
}

void subnum(int x, int y) {

    cout << x - y;
}

int main() {

    int a, b;
    cin >> a;
    cin >> b;
    cout << addnum(a, b);
    cout << subnum(a, b);
}
```

This code is used for calculation as you can see its very basic yet i dont know why it isnt working

Comment: Your functions return `void`, so no value is returned from them, and we can't print such "non-value".

Comment: please include the error message you get. It should contains some hints on what is wrong here

Comment: look, you have `cout` in your procedure, you can use not `cout` in your main body and write `addnum(a, b)` instead of `cout<<addnumb(a,b)`. if you want use `cout` in your body and capture result of the function you wrote, you should use `return` in your function code, so you can `cout` the result of your function.
so, you need  to use not `void` type functions. in your case `int` type will do the work.

Comment: `std::cout` is not an operator. It's an object. The operators here are the `<<`s.

Answer (score 1):

`addnum` and `subnum` return `void`. `void` isn't a type that can be inserted into an `ostream`.

You probably want to change `addnum` to `return x+y` and `subnum` to `return x-y`.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that your function already calls `cout`. Therefore, there is no need to call `cout` **again** when calling the function.

Simply replace

`cout<< addnum(a,b);
cout<<subnum(a,b);`

with

```
addnum(a,b); subnum(a,b);
```

Comment: As other people have pointed out, the reason why this does not work is because the function prints out the result, but then returns no value (void), which cout does not know how to print (in layman's terms).